# Java regular expressions for specific name\value format

Tags: java, regex

I'm not familiar yet with java regular expressions. I want to validate a string that has the following format:

```
String INPUT = "[name1 value1];[name2 value2];[name3 value3];";
```

namei and valuei are Strings should contain any characters expect white-space.

I tried with this expression:

```
String REGEX = "([\\S*\\s\\S*];)*";
```

But if I call matches() I get always false even for a good String.

what's the best regular expression for it?

Comment: post your attempts

Comment: http://regexone.com/ I really recommend to learn it once, then use it whole life ;) Website link is really good, many examples and test your knowledge after every portion of new information. And just to let you know, people are not likely to help if they see you didn't even try to solve it yourself.

Comment: Try reading on writing regex, then you will see how simple this is! Just try something.

Comment: I tried but just I didn't post it sorry!!

the post is now updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
(?:\[\w.*?\s\w.*?\];)*
```

If you want to only match three of these, replace the `*` at the end with `{3}`.

Explanation:

- `(?:`: Start of non-capturing group
- `\[`: Escapes the `[` sign which is a meta-character in regex. This
  allows it to be used for matching.
- `\w.*?`: Lazily matches any word character `[a-z][A-Z][0-9]_`. Lazy matching means it attempts to match the character as few times possible, in this case meaning that when will stop matching once it finds the following `\s`.
- `\s`: Matches one whitespace
- `\]`: See `\[`
- `;`: Matches one semicolon
- `)`: End of non-capturing group
- `*`: Matches any number of what is contained in the preceding non-capturing group.

[See this link for demonstration](https://regex101.com/r/wM1xD5/2)

Comment: your answer isn't the right one but it helped me to find the right expression.
thank you

Comment: @KallelOmar Then please consider accepting this answer. If you hover the accept button, it says to accept answers that helped you find the true answer, even if the answer itself was not completely correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should escape square brackets. Also, if your aim is to match only three, replace `*`  with `{3}`

```
(\[\\S*\\s\\S*\];){3}
```